# Why can't my hosts communicate with each other?

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming, mininet, sdn

I've written the following Mininet topology for k-ary fat-trees.

```py
from mininet.topo import Topo

class FatTreeTopo(Topo):
    def build(self, k=4):
        # k is the parameter that determines the size of the Fat-Tree

        # spine switches
        spine_switches = [self.addSwitch(f"spn{i}") for i in range((k//2)**2)]

        # |pods| = k

        # fabric switches
        fab_switches = [self.addSwitch(f"fab{i}") for i in range(k**2//2)]

        # tor switches
        tor_switches = [self.addSwitch(f"tor{i}") for i in range(k**2//2)]

        # servers
        servers = [self.addHost(f"srv{i}") for i in range(k**3//4)]

        # Connect core switches to aggregation switches
        for c in range((k//2)**2):
            for pod in range(k):
                f = pod * (k//2) + c//(k//2)
                self.addLink(spine_switches[c], fab_switches[f])

        # Connect fabric switches to tor switches
        for f in range((k**2)//2):
            si = f//(k//2) * (k//2)
            for t in range(si, si + k//2):
                self.addLink(fab_switches[f], tor_switches[t])

        # Connect tor switches to servers
        for t in range((k**2)//2):
            si = t * (k//2)
            for s in range(si, si + k//2):
                self.addLink(tor_switches[t], servers[s])
```

When I run this code for `k=4` none of my hosts (named `srv#`) can ping each other (tested by running `pingall`). For example `srv0 ping srv1` returns the 'Destination Host Unreachable' message, however both the hosts are connected to the `tor0` switch and can ping the switch, so I'm unsure why the switch does not forward messages between them.

The same code does work for `k=2` and `k=3`, and I can successfully send messages between hosts.